# Scan git objects for commit w/o checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

Is there a way to read all the files pertaining to a git commit without running git checkout? Doesnt a commit point to a bunch of blobs in the .git folder? Is there a way to read those blobs directly given a commit id? or is it just more straightforward to run `git checkout`? I am just trying to audit the files for vulnerabilities like plain text passwords etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's `git unpack-file $blob_id`, that drops a copy of the blob's content at the work tree root with a junk name, which it prints.

There's also `git cat-file --batch`, which takes an optional format and some more tweaks, and pipes all the requested output.  If you've got control of your auditing tool's input handling that will be by far the most efficient:

```
git ls-files -s | cut -d' ' -f2- \
| git cat-file --batch='%(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' \
| your audit tool
```

and for a commit it'd start `git ls-tree -r $thatcommit | cut -d' ' -f3-`

Answer (score 1):

In orden to see an object (and get it on stdout) you can  do:

```
git show some-branch-or-revision:file-path
git cat-file -p object-id
```

Either of those would work.

Answer (score 1):

... and to see a list of files contained in a commit use

```
git ls-tree -r <commit id>
```

This list will contain the blob ids of the file data, so you can use cat-file as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is possible with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022):
"[`git ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8e56affcb52e2cf344437a892356a419985ea4ba/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files))</sup> learns the `--format` option to tweak its output.

So instead of [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104418/6309) which uses:

- `git ls-files -s | cut -d' ' -f2-`  to get each file commit
- `git cat-file --batch='%(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)'`

You can directly do, with Git 2.38+, preceded by [`git unpack-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-unpack-file):

```
git unpack-file $blob_id
git ls-files --format='%(path) %(objectname) %(objectsize)'
```

See [commit ce74de9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce74de931d7aea9746e37632534eacc63b0c1a90) (23 Jul 2022) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8e56aff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e56affcb52e2cf344437a892356a419985ea4ba), 03 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce74de931d7aea9746e37632534eacc63b0c1a90): introduce "--format" option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> Add a new option "`--format`" that outputs index entries information in a custom format, taking inspiration from the option with the same name in the [`git ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce74de931d7aea9746e37632534eacc63b0c1a90/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree))</sup> command.
>
> "`--format`" cannot used with "`-s`", "`-o`", "`-k`", "`-t`", "`--resolve-undo`","`--deduplicate`" and "`--eol`".

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce74de931d7aea9746e37632534eacc63b0c1a90/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L195-L201):

> ### `--format=<format>`
>
> A string that interpolates `%(fieldname)` from the result being shown.
> It also interpolates `%%` to `%`, and `%xx` where `xx` are hex digits
> interpolates to character with hex code `xx`;
>
> For example `%00`
> interpolates to `\0` (NUL), `%09` to `\t` (TAB) and %0a to `\n` (LF).
>
> `--format` cannot be combined with `-s`, `-o`, `-k`, `-t`, `--resolve-undo`
> and `--eol`.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce74de931d7aea9746e37632534eacc63b0c1a90/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L233-L262):

> It is possible to print in a custom format by using the `--format`
> option, which is able to interpolate different fields using
> a `%(fieldname)` notation.
>
> For example, if you only care about the
> "objectname" and "path" fields, you can execute with a specific
> "`--format`" like
>
> git ls-files --format='%(objectname) %(path)'
>
> ### FIELD NAMES
>
> The way each path is shown can be customized by using the
> `--format=<format>` option, where the `%(fieldname)` in the
> `<format>` string for various aspects of the index entry are
> interpolated.
>
> The following "fieldname" are understood:
>
> #### `objectmode`
>
> The mode of the file which is recorded in the index.
>
> #### `objectname`
>
> The name of the file which is recorded in the index.
>
> #### `stage`
>
> The stage of the file which is recorded in the index.
>
> #### `eolinfo:index`
>
> #### `eolinfo:worktree`
>
> The `<eolinfo>` (see the description of the `--eol` option) of
> the contents in the index or in the worktree for the path.
>
> #### `eolattr`
>
> The `<eolattr>` (see the description of the `--eol` option)
> that applies to the path.
>
> #### `path`
>
> The pathname of the file which is recorded in the index.

---

Note: if you are using `git ls-files --format="%(path)`, [use Git 2.41 (Q2 2023)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1071deae006ab5b43ee530ee681eb20a7accc020).

---

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) updates the documentation.

See [commit 3744ffc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b) (15 Jun 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e0e8a2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0e8a2dfa05d66562688804ec38939d8bb56a8fd), 22 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ls-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b): fix documentation of `%x` format placeholder
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [`ls-tree --format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L86)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree#Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup> expands %x followed by two hexadecimal digits to the character indicated by that hexadecimal number, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-tree --format=%x41 HEAD | head -1
> A
> ```
>
> It rejects % followed by a hexadecimal digit, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-tree --format=%41 HEAD | head -1
> fatal: bad ls-tree format: element '41' does not start with '('
> ```
>
> This functionality is provided by `strbuf_expand_literal_cb()`, which has not been changed since it was factored out by [fd2015b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd2015b323d283c73346d70d2285a927650bb60a) ("`strbuf`: separate callback for `strbuf_expand`:ing literals", 2019-01-28, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42977bf5c7306e4c2dded5353f39cf087cf23a1f) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)).
>
> Adjust the documentation accordingly.

`git ls-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3744ffcbcdcd5a619b7522671e6137b33d84626b/Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt#L89-L91):

> `%xNN` where `NN` are hex digits interpolates to character
> with hex code `NN`; for example `%x00` interpolates to
> `\0` (NUL), `%x09` to `\t` (TAB) and `%x0a` to `\n` (LF).